# need help to understand conditional probability

Tags: probability

So this question, I don't anderstand the line above;  how it jumps from P(H|Fn) to the summation on the other side. Does it apply bayes formula or what?

Comment: apply definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(H|F_n \cap C_i)P(C_i|F_n)=\dfrac{P(H \cap F_n \cap C_i)}{P(F_n \cap C_i)}.\dfrac{P(F_n \cap C_i)}{P(F_n)}=\dfrac{P(H \cap F_n \cap C_i)}{P(F_n)}$. Now, $C_i's$ are disjoint, and so $P(\cup C_i)=\sum P(C_i)=1$.

So, $\sum P(H \cap F_n \cap C_i) = P(\cup_{i=1}^{n} (H \cap F_n \cap C_i))=P(H \cap F_n )$. So, LHS=RHS.

Comment: sorry, so what formula did u use? (bayes or demorgan, or what) It wasn't clear to me at the first glance?

Comment: I used the definition!

Comment: $P(A|B)=\dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

Comment: what do you mean by "I used the definition"?

Comment: Oh- this is just the definition :)
Sorry if you didn't know it- but wait- now you do know it. This is how knowledge progresses. Hope it helped.